# ant task to log in to a remote unix server and replace a token in directory of files

Tags: unix, ant, ssh, replace

Hi
I want to write an ant script that connects to remote linux/unix host and replace occurrences of a token in all files in a directory and subdirectories.

the script will get host name and login credentials and a directory and a token to replace and will operate.

I have been able to do it locally with replace task and i know there is sshexec task as well. is there a way to combine them together ?

what's a good way of doing it ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To execute Ant on a remote host, Ant will need to be on that box and your buildfile will need to be there too. You should then be able to sshexec it remotely.

Depending on your environment (e.g. is this a build environment?), you might consider using the AntServer and RemoteAnt tasks in [ant-contrib server tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html) as an alternative.